# Calculating the size of list everytime or keep the size in variable and used

Tags: java

Calculating the size of arraylist everytime, or it is good to store the size of array list variable and use it. The arraylist containing less than 100 values.

Will the variable present inside the method will take much memory, anyhow the variables present in the method will be eligible for garbage collection.

please suggest storing the size of list in variable or calculate the size of list every time ?

Comment: Since here we are talking about 100 values and calling size() on an ArrayList is a constant-time O(1) operation - in both cases the performance impact is negligible.

Comment: Are you talking about the standard ArrayList type from the java.util package, or are you asking about implementing your own version of a list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you look in the implementation of ArrayList you can see that they already store the size in a variable themself, so no need for you to store it yourself.